# PHP strip_tags html validation and bracket check?

Tags: php, html, validation, strip-tags

I use at the moment `strip_tags($content, '<a>')` tag to clear html tags except `<a>` tag.

Example 1: `Example "lorem ipsum dolor <sit amet....."` it cuts everything after "`<`"

Example 2: If the content starts with `"<test lorem ipsum"` I get only empty string.

I tried to check it with regex but the outcome is the same.

`preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content)` it returns the same result for validation.

I need somehow to clear html and keep correct using of "`<`" bracket inside the content.

Comment: Well… `<` delimits a tag. `strip_html` removes any tags. If you want a "<" in HTML, you need to encode it as `&lt;`.

Comment: @deceze is correct, if you want greater than or less than to not be taken as a tag you would use &gt; or &lt; to indicate then respectively.

Comment: @marco You mean [`strip_tags`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and not `strip_html`?

Comment: @yunzen I use exactly `strip_tags()`

Comment: @MarcoTesini Hey, could you react to my code?
I've tested it (the second one) again and it works as it deletes every html tag except `<a …>` and `</a>`.
If it doesn't help you, you could say why or what's wrong with my code…

Answer (score -1):

If you want to clear every tag except plain `<a>` and `</a>`, you could just filter them, replace them, then clear the HTML and replace them back, like this:

```
<?php
    $text = "<a> ahahahasjusjhcbzdeu <div>JEY ssjisuj</div>jn<p> here somehing else </p></a>";

    $EndText = str_replace("<a>", "&ATL", $text);
    $EndText = str_replace("</a>", "&ATR", $EndText);

    $EndText = strip_tags($EndText);

    $EndText = str_replace("&ATL", "<a>", $EndText);
    $EndText = str_replace("&ATR", "</a>", $EndText);

    echo htmlspecialchars($EndText);
?>
```

But if you want to get something like `<a href="mywebsite.com"> here </a>`, the link would get deleted, too.
So you need to filter the text between `<a` and `>` out (that can be done with `explode`, `sub_str` and `str_replace`), then do the same as in the solution above and then paste it in again.
A code that would do this is:

```
<?php
    $text = "<a>Here something</a><div>Again<a href='website.com'>That's a better link</a> Here</div>";

    $Texts = explode("<a", $text);
    $Begin = strip_tags(array_shift($Texts));
    $Middles = [];
    foreach ($Texts as &$value) {
        $Middle = explode(">", $value)[0];
        array_push($Middles, $Middle);

        $Position = strpos($value, ">");
        $value = substr($value, $Position+1);
        $value = str_replace("</a>", "&htlENDA&", $value);
        $value = strip_tags($value);

    }

    $EndText = $Begin;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Texts); $i++) {
        $EndText = $EndText."<a".$Middles[$i].">".$Texts[$i];
    }

    $EndText = str_replace("&htlENDA&", "</a>", $EndText);

    echo "<br><br>Ende: ".htmlspecialchars($EndText);

?>
```

That would solve your problem, as it deletes every html tag except `<a ... >` and `</a>`